# Selecting values only for last day of month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that's supposed to grab only the value for the last day of the month from all my existing records (so the last day of multiple months). I'm unable to get the value I'm needing for ONLY the last day, due to using a SUM() clause. This is adding all the values for the whole month together. Can I get only the value for the last day another way? Is there something I'm missing?

Code so far:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name], 
    Year([ValDate]) & IIf(Len(Month([ValDate]))>1,Month([ValDate]),"0" & Month([ValDate])) AS BalMonth, 
    Sum(Value) AS LastValue
FROM 
    Archive
GROUP BY 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name], 
    Year([ValDate]), 
    Month([ValDate])
ORDER BY 
    ID, 
    Year(ValDate) & Month(ValDate)
```

Other Code tested:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name], 
    YEAR([ValDate]) & MONTH([ValDate]) & MAX(DAY([BalDate])) AS LastDayofMonth
FROM 
    Archive
GROUP BY 
    ID , 
    [Customer Name], 
    YEAR([ValDate]), 
    MONTH([ValDate])
ORDER BY 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name], 
    YEAR([ValDate]), 
    MONTH([ValDate])
```

The second section of code didn't work as it produces the dates in `YYYYMMDD` format. This makes it so it doesn't allow proper ordering of the dates. Instead, the dates are being ordered as 1 , 10 , 11 , 12 , 2 , 3 , 4 , etc.

If anything is unclear I'll try my best to clarify, just let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name], 
    [ValDate] AS LastDayofMonth,
    Sum([FieldToSum]) As Total
FROM 
    Archive
GROUP BY 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name],
    [ValDate]
HAVING
    [ValDate] = DateSerial(Year([ValDate]), Month([ValDate]) + 1, 0)
```

Edit:

To have a *formatted* date output, try this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name], 
    Format([ValDate], "yyyymmdd") AS LastDayofMonth,
    Sum([FieldToSum]) As Total
FROM 
    Archive
WHERE
    [ValDate] = DateSerial(Year([ValDate]), Month([ValDate]) + 1, 0)
GROUP BY 
    ID, 
    [Customer Name],
    Format([ValDate], "yyyymmdd")
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much! Am I able to get rid of the "/"s from the dates? I'm needing to also export this query through VBA after throwing it through a formula that divides. The "/"s try to divide within the dates instead of being read as column headers.

Comment: @Symon - Bear in mind that your dates will [become variant (string)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-function-6f29d87b-8761-408d-81d3-63b9cd842530) types - they're no longer dates.

Comment: This is perfect! You're awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Paul - Thank you for the heads-up! I went ahead and tested the output and all seems to be how I'm needing it and in the proper order. I appreciate the input!